# Using regex for A-Z, 0-9, - and dot?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a long method like this, that has hard coded each character. Is there a way to use `Regex` for something like this, to make it much *shorter*, and much *easier*?

```
private static bool IsValid(char character)
{
    return new List<char>(new[]
    {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
        'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
        'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '.'
    }).Contains(character);
}
```

Comment: Pattern like this `[a-z0-9\.\-]` Ranges `a-z`, `0-9` and two more values `.` and `-`

Comment: regex is expensive though, what's wrong with this method? btw, you are creating the array every time you call the method, it would be better to cache it in a field. and it's also not clear why you are creating a list because array also has the `Contains` method.

Comment: Or may be something like `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.-".Contains(character);` from `System.Linq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to check *ranges*, e.g.

```
private static bool IsValid(char character) {
  return character >= 'a' && character <= 'z' || // letters
         character >= '0' && character <= '9' || // digits
         character == '-' ||                     // special characters
         character == '.';
}
```

Techically, you can use *regular expressions* but it is an *overshoot*:

```
private static bool IsValid(char character) {
  return Regex.IsMatch(character.ToString(), @"[a-z0-9\.\-]");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a BITWISE operator instead of boolean operator? that is `|` instead of `||` ?

Comment: @Aniket Inge: Thank you! I'm sorry for the typo

Comment: No problem! Cheers

Comment: Thank you, I decided to go with the latter, it seemed more minimalist and simple. Thanks!